# probplot - define color

Tags: matlab, plot

I have these lines in matlab:

```
pp1=probplot('normal',one_stone);           
set(pp1,'color','red')
```

This gives a plot that's red all over.

I would like to change the color of the scatter WITHOUT changing the color of the trendline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set properties of the line and the markers separately like this:

```
set(pp1(1),'Color','r') % line
set(pp2(2),'Color','b') % markers
```